# Error on django-heroku install with pipenv

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework, pipenv

pretty new to Django here. Not sure the problem.

- elementary os 0.4.1 loki
- django 2.1
- django-rest-framework 3.8.2
- gunicorn
- python 3.7

So i'm in my `pipenv shell` and run `pipenv install django-heroku`. And I get this crazy error:

```
An error occurred while installing psycopg2==2.8.2 --hash=sha256:00cfecb3f3db6eb76dcc763e71777da56d12b6d61db6a2c6ccbbb0bff5421f8f --hash=sha256:076501fc24ae13b2609ba2303d88d4db79072562f0b8cc87ec1667dedff99dc1 --hash=sha256:4e2b34e4c0ddfeddf770d7df93e269700b080a4d2ec514fec668d71895f56782 --hash=sha256:5cacf21b6f813c239f100ef78a4132056f93a5940219ec25d2ef833cbeb05588 --hash=sha256:61f58e9ecb9e4dc7e30be56b562f8fc10ae3addcfcef51b588eed10a5a66100d --hash=sha256:8954ff6e47247bdd134db602fcadfc21662835bd92ce0760f3842eacfeb6e0f3 --hash=sha256:b6e8c854cdc623028e558a409b06ea2f16d13438335941c7765d0a42b5bedd33 --hash=sha256:baca21c0f7344576346e260454d0007313ccca8c170684707a63946b27a56c8f --hash=sha256:bb1735378770fb95dbe392d29e71405d45c8bdcfa064f916504833a92ab03c55 --hash=sha256:de3d3c46c1ee18f996db42d1eb44cf1565cc9e38fb1dbd9b773ff6b3fa8035d7 --hash=sha256:dee885602bb200bdcb1d30f6da6c7bb207360bc786d0a364fe1540dd14af0bab! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 8/8 — 00:00:04
Installing initially failed dependencies…
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1874, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       keep_outdated=keep_outdated
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/home/andrew/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting psycopg2==2.8.2 (from -r /tmp/pipenv-iaa8p0mr-requirements/pipenv-n1t1lb2p-requirement.txt (line 1))', '  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/23/7e/93c325482c328619870b6cd09370f6dbe1148283daca65115cd63642e60f/psycopg2-2.8.2.tar.gz']
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:', '    ERROR: running egg_info', '    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info', '    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO', '    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt', '    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt', "    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'", '    ', '    Error: pg_config executable not found.', '    ', '    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory', '    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the', '    option:', '    ', '        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...', '    ', "    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.", '    ', '    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI', "    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.", '    ', "    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at", '    <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html>).', '    ', '    ----------------------------------------', 'ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-kjdpr2oc/psycopg2/']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

As a work-around, when working locally, I comment out

```
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

in `settings.py` but then uncomment them when pushing to heroku. Works fine, but I'd love to not have a new commit with the message `added settings lines for heroku` every single time I push to heroku.

Any advice on how I can get django-heroku to actually install with pipenv?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is `pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory`. So i did `sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2` for ubuntu. If it is not working for your os try following 
http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#install-from-source

Comment: Thanks! First I ran `sudo apt install python-psycopg2`. Then, as per that link, I tried `sudo apt install libpq-dev` in order to install pg_config, and that's what did it. It works!